# How to use substring in JMeter XPath extractor

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter

Xpath:

```
//*[local-name()='InputFolder']/text()
```

Above Xpath gives me this result

Result:

```
Match[1]=Input\ABC_DATA_ADMIN_26050
```

But here I dont want "Input" String I only need `ABC_DATA_ADMIN` in my variable

Please suggest me a way to overcome this

I tried looking up the substring but could not figure out, how to use it

Comment: The XPath `substring(//*[local-name()='InputFolder']/text(), 8, 14)` [will do what you need](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/fd731850f16d2e45d4bd2e912da2efb1) and hopefully show you how to use the substring function. The issue is that the substring function may not work for every case, in which case it might be easier if you gave us more examples of the values you're trying to match. You might also be able to get some use out of `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

Comment: thanks looks like it worked in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is using XPath `substring-after()` function which I think will be cleaner for your case compared to `substring()`, for example :

```
substring-after(//*[local-name()='InputFolder'], 'Input\')
```

Output :

```
ABC_DATA_ADMIN_26050
```